# Specify target API level in Layout xml android?

Tags: android

I needed to add a `digital clock` in the layout. My `min-supported` API level is 14. I found out that there is a `digital clock` widget for API level below 17 (After that it got deprecated), and there is a `text clock` for API 17 and above.

So one thing I can do is to add both layout in xml and dynamically set the visibility based on version number in the code. But the xml will continuously show me that I have used `Text Clock` while my `min-supported` level is 14. So:

1. Is there a way in the xml to specify to ignore the `min-sdk` error. Something like

   ```
   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
   ```

That we use in the normal java code.

2. Is there a way in XML to specify to use a particular widget based on version number. Some kind of if else statement in the xml that says:

   ```
   if((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
       //Use text clock
   } else {
       // Use digital clock
   }
   ```

Comment: `Text Clock` should be fully backwards compatible...

Answer (score 13):

you can use the tools target api

```
<item name="android:fontFamily" tools:targetApi="jelly_bean">sans-serif-light</item>
```

this will also work

```
<item name="android:fontFamily" tools:targetApi="17">sans-serif-light</item>
```

Comment: Don't get why this answer got so many upvotes, "tools:targetApi" won't do anything. To target specific API you have to create different resource folder as answered by @jlopez here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30434712/5636313